# DatePicker solo me muestre año y no se puede editar

Tags: c#, mvc, razor

Tengo el siguiente código que estoy trabajando en MVC 5 Boostrap y Razor

```
       @Html.TextBox("Agno", String.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")), new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @required = "required" })
```

Pero solo me muestra el `control DatePicker` y lo que deseo es solo seleccionar el año, Seleccionar! no Editar! ¿Se puede hacer esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes mostrar capturas? No queda del todo claro lo que preguntas.

Comment: @sakulino esta es la captura solo deseo que se pueda visualizar el año, sin día, ni mes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que lo mejor es que hagas algo como esto:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class='col-sm-6'>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            viewMode: 'years',
            format: 'YYYY'
        });
    });

    </script>
</div>
```

debes tener encuentra referenciar todo boostrap y jQuery

Espero te ayude

Answer (score 1):

Tuve un problema similar y lo arreglé modificando `@readonly = false`. En tu caso quedaría así:

```
@Html.TextBox("Agno", String.Format("{0:d}", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")), new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @required = "required", @readonly = false })
```

Comment: solo me inhabilita el control!!!!

Comment: Le pusiste true o false? En el ejemplo que pongo va false, eso quiere decir que el control NO será de solo lectura

Comment: exactamente como lo tienes con false

Answer (score 1):

Desconozco cómo tienes declarado tu `datepicker` pero si defines en javascript así:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker( {
    format: "yyyy",
    startView: "year", 
    minViewMode: "year"
});
```

Ya de inicio sólo seleccionará y mostrará año. [Aquí](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#startdate) tienes la documentación.